# Efficient pytorch broadcasting not found

Tags: pytorch, array-broadcasting

I have the following code snippet in my implemenatation. There is a nested for loop with 3 loops. In the main code the 3D coordinates of the original system is stacked as a 1D vector of constinous stacking of points as for a point with coordinate (x,y,z) a sample cells will look like

```
Predictions =[...x,y,z,...]
```

whereas for my calulation I need reshaped_prediction vector as a 2D matrix with `prediction_reshaped[i][0]=x, prediction_reshaped[i][1]=y prediction_reshaped[i][2]=z`
where i is any sample row in the matrix `prediction_reshaped`.
The following code shows the logic

```
prediction_reshaped=torch.zeros([batch,num_node,dimesion])
    for i in range(batch):
        for j in range(num_node):
            for k in range(dimesion):
                prediction_reshaped[i][j][k]=prediction[i][3*j+k]
```

is their any efficient broadcasting to avoid these three nested loop? it is slowing down my code. torch.reshape does not suit my purpose.
The code is implemented using pytorch with all matrices as pytorch tensor but any numpy solution will also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```py
import torch
batch = 2
num_nodes = 4
x = torch.rand(batch, num_nodes * 3)
# tensor([[0.8076, 0.2572, 0.7100, 0.4180, 0.6420, 0.4668, 0.8915, 0.0366,  0.5704,
#          0.0834, 0.3313, 0.9080],
#         [0.2925, 0.7367, 0.8013, 0.4516, 0.5470, 0.5123, 0.1929, 0.4191,  0.1174,
#          0.0076, 0.2864, 0.9151]])
x = x.reshape(batch, num_nodes, 3)
# tensor([[[0.8076, 0.2572, 0.7100],
#         [0.4180, 0.6420, 0.4668],
#         [0.8915, 0.0366, 0.5704],
#         [0.0834, 0.3313, 0.9080]],
#
#        [[0.2925, 0.7367, 0.8013],
#         [0.4516, 0.5470, 0.5123],
#         [0.1929, 0.4191, 0.1174],
#         [0.0076, 0.2864, 0.9151]]])
```